# Is changing document.submit() to window.location in case of redirecting page to a url with some variabel the right decision?

Tags: javascript, forms, window.location

I find if these code doesn't work in FF dan chrome

```
document.forms[0].action ="url";
document.forms[0].submit();
```

and I decide to substitue them with:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){window.location="url";});
```

Is that the right decision?

Comment: it depends on server, if the server supports both GET and POST protocol then it is right

Comment: Okay..thanks  Arun P Johny. That window.location works in all browsers, I just want to make sure that the change will not take bad effect that I don't know

Comment: yes, it works every where. You need to worry only about the request method like GET/POST/PUT etc. window.location redirect will be a GET request

Comment: Replacing a form submit with window.location won't post any data from the form. Not really a valid substitution. 

I see no problem with the code you listed as not working. Tested in both Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/zhwD4/

Comment: Okay.. then I will look for it...they throw the variable via url (querystring)... that is get, isn't that?

Comment: if the <form> tag doesn't mention the method it use..then what method will be used in server( get/post/put)?